TypeScript failing to infer type is not undefined after type guard with logical or
In the code below, in the else block, it is clear that b cannot be undefined (a||b is truthy and a is falsy so b must be truthy).
Why does Typescript produce the error 'b' is possibly 'undefined', and how can I avoid this error?
function test(a: string | undefined, b: string | undefined) {
  if (a || b) {
    if (a) {
      const x = a.length
    } else {
      const y = b.length
    }
  }
}


if (a || b) doesn't alter either type, a and b are still both string | undefined. if (a) narrows a to string, but has no impact on b (which isn't involved in that expression) at all. You have information the compiler doesn't, just do b!.length.

Or maybe it's just simpler to skip the first if (a || b) and just do if (a) { /* use a */ } else if (b) { /* use b */ } else { return; }.

@jonrsharpe thanks, I would accept this as the answer if I could

@VLAZ I trimmed down the code for this question but there is a lot more code in the if (a||b) block in my actual code, which is why it's structured that way. Otherwise I agree, if it was just the code above, it would be better to split it as you said

You can debug it like this:
function test(a: string | undefined, b: string | undefined) {
  type A1 = typeof a; // string | undefined
  type B1 = typeof b; // string | undefined
  if (a || b) {
    type A2 = typeof a; // string | undefined
    type B2 = typeof b; // string | undefined
    if (a) {
      type A3 = typeof a; // string
      type B3 = typeof b; // string | undefined
      const x = a.length
    } else {
      type A4 = typeof a; // string | undefined
      type B4 = typeof b; // string | undefined
      const y = b.length
    }
  }
}

Basically, (a || b) is not able to narrow down the types.
The conditional flow analysis look for !== undefined and !== null checks (this is a known limitation of TS), you should re-write it as follows:
function test(a: string | undefined, b: string | undefined) {
  if (a !== undefined ) {
    const x = a.length; // number
  } else if(b !== undefined){
    const y = b.length; // number
  }
}


You might want to link to something like https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30869 that explains why TS doesn't narrow in this case

@jcalz very insightful link, thanks

Both a and b are defined as string | undefined which means typescript expects them to either have a value or be undefined. You can either remove the undefined type definition (or) if you are sure the function receives the value, add a ! (non-null assertion operator) operator before accessing the length.
for example :
const x = a!.length


read more here: non-null assertion operator
